# Then $F_a$ divides $F_{an}$, $n \in \Bbb{N}$ where $F_i$ denotes the $i$-th Fibonacci number.

Tags: calculus, analysis, discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $a$ be a fixed natural number. Then $F_a$ divides $F_{an}$, $n \in \Bbb{N}$ where $F_i$ denotes the $i$-th Fibonacci number.

For $n=1$ the result is true. Let it be true for $n=k$.

$$\begin{align}F_{ka+a} &= F_{ka+(a-1)} + F_{ka+(a-2)} \\
&= 2F_{ka+(a-2)} + F_{ka+(a-3)}\\
&= 3F_{ka+(a-3)} + 2F_{ka+(a-4)}\\
&= 5F_{ka+(a-4)} + 3F_{ka+(a-3)} = ...\\
&= F_aF_{ka+1} + F_{a-1} F_{ka}\end{align} $$

Thus $F_a$ divides $F_{(k+1)a}$. Hence the result is true by induction.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: The dots in the proof need a proof.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the dots in your proof, show by (strong) induction with respect to $n$, that a more general identity holds:
$$F_{n+m+1}=F_{m+1}F_{n+1}+F_{m}F_{n}.$$
Then apply it for $m=a-1$ and $n=ka$, to find directly what you need
$$F_{ka+a} = F_aF_{ka+1} + F_{a-1} F_{ka}.$$
For the inductive step:
$$\begin{align}
F_{n+m+2}&=F_{n+m}+F_{n+m+1}\\
&=(F_{m+1}F_{n}+F_{m}F_{n-1})+(F_{m+1}F_{n+1}+F_{m}F_{n})\\
&=F_{m+1}(F_n+F_{n+1})+F_m(F_{n-1}+F_n)\\
&=F_{m+1}F_{n+2}+F_mF_{n+1}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @user8795 Are you still interested in your question? Any further doubt/comment?

Answer (score 0):

The outer induction is good if the inner one is, but the inner induction is rather hand-wavy. Pull it out as a lemma and state it precisely. It may be worth generalising to $F_{m+n}$ in terms of $F_m$ and $F_n$.